# installing seaborn without sudo

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, seaborn, web2py-modules

I am trying to install seaborn without using sudo. I have already installed on my python 2.7 and windows 7 setting with the following cmd commands :

```
 pip install pandas
 pip install xlrd 
 pip install matplotlib
```

and they all were installed like charm.

```
`pip install seaborn` did not work
```

i have attached the error message.[last lines of emssage[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stQlR.png)

Comment: Welcome to dependency hell with Python. It looks like pip is looking for `lapack/blas` on your machine- these are compiled linear algebra libraries. You can add them, but (in my opinion), by far the easiest way to work around this is to use Anaconda Python- seaborn comes with it so you don't have to manually install it, and I don't think it needs sudo to install. Here's a link: https://docs.continuum.io/

Comment: so why is Anaconda better than Pycharm for example ?

Comment: You cannot compare Anaconda with Pycharm (that would be like asking why Windows is better than AcrobatReader or so). Pycharm is an IDE and not relevant here. Anaconda is a python distribution which has many useful packages included, such they work nicely together. Also installing new packages with anaconda is often much easier than using pip.

Comment: @William Install Anaconda to replace your Python, then use PyCharm to write code that runs on Anaconda's version of Python. Two different tools. To use an analogy, if Python is a car, then Anaconda Python is that car with addons you want (like Seaborn) and PyCharm is the driver that comes with the car. You can use PyCharm together with Anaconda or with regular Python. Pycharm can "drive" either.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in installing [precompiled python wheel binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for Windows.

That, or use something like [Anaconda python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Comment: The wheel package allows python's setuptools to compile wheel binaries. It's different. Wheel binaries by themselves is a binary format for packaged and compiled python modules that pip is able to install.